# Passing variable as generic type

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to get the current class type, from a base class, and pass it as a parameter.

The code should do something like this:

```
public BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        var MyType = GetType();
        var A = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(...);
    }
}
```

so if it is instanced like this:

```
public class MyObject : BaseClass
```

then the last call would do:

```
 var A = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(...);
```

but I can't find how to pass the type as a parameter.

any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Where you call `DeserializeObject` you know the type?

Comment: I would like to call it from the base constructor, so at this point GetType will return me the type of the derived class.

Comment: Generics are a compile time feature, `GetType` returns the type at runtime. So this doesnt work. The derived types should call it because they know their type.

Comment: so have to see if the json lib accepts a type as a parameter instead; since I guess they manually instantiate the resulting class

Comment: Does it allow you to Deserialize as an object of type <T>?

Comment: Just found that Json.net allows: JsonConvert.PopulateObject(..., this); which does exactly what I intended

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, Type type)`.
It allows you to specify the type of the object you want to build.

```
public BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        var MyType = GetType();
        var A = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ json blob }", MyType);
    }
}
```

`A` will be of type `MyType`. 
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is returning an `object` you will have to cast the result to what you want at some point.

The documentation is available [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_4.htm)